# NotePad++ replace problem

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with lots of text editing using NotePad++.

for example

`<span class="italic">some text</span><span class="bold">another text or some text</span>`

I would like to use NotePad++'s regex replace to replace

`<span class"italic>some text</span>` to `<i>some text</i>` and `<span class="bold">another text or some text</span>` to `<b>another text or some text</b>`

I'm able to match the span text however How to replace them with NotePad++

Find `<span class="italic">text12312</span>` and replace it with `<i>[a-zA-Z]*</i>` will actually put the `"[a-zA-Z]*"` text into replaced string and not `"text12312"`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`<span class="italic">([^<]+)</span>` => `<i>\1</i>`

`<span class="bold">([^<]+)</span>` => `<b>\1</b>`

`[^<]+` matches one or more of any character except `<`, and the parentheses capture it in group #1. `\1` inserts the captured text into the replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex like: `<span class="italic">([\w\s\d]+)</span>`

and replacement like: `<i>$1</i>`

The important point here is to create a matching group for your text by surrounding it in brackets i.e. `([\w\s\d]+)` which matches one or more:

- `\w` word chars
- `\s` space chars
- `\d` numeric chars

Now in your replacement string, reference the first and only matched group with `$1`.

Comment: `<span class="italic">some text and <span class="custom"> some more </span> text </span>`

Comment: @Amarghosh, as stated in the question, OP only wants to match `[A-Za-z]` in between the span tag which precludes the need to check for nested spans.

Comment: He uses `[a-zA-Z]*` and his sample text contains digits - I was just suggesting that if his text is large enough, sooner or later he'll realize that its not a good idea even to search-n-replace html with regex

Comment: Are yo sure it is working in notepad++? it doesn't work with me.

Comment: NPP uses `\1` in the replacement string, not `$1` like most other regex tools.  Also, NPP doesn't support class shorthands (`\w`, `\s`, etc.).  If it did support them, `\d` would be redundant because `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

example from notepad : 
trying to replace this text:
 0x0145 test 
with this text:
[0x0145] test

[image]