# Using RegEx to insert data by the nth term

Tags: regex

I would like to add a term after an nth term with the previous term substituted in. For instance, how would I change the following in notpad++:

***x***<sub>1</sub> ***y***<sub>1</sub> ***z***<sub>1</sub> ***a***<sub>1</sub> ***b***<sub>1</sub> ***c***<sub>1</sub>

***x***<sub>2</sub> ***y***<sub>2</sub> ***z***<sub>2</sub> ***a***<sub>2</sub> ***b***<sub>2</sub> ***c***<sub>2</sub>

***x***<sub>3</sub> ***y***<sub>3</sub> ***z***<sub>3</sub> ***a***<sub>3</sub> ***b***<sub>3</sub> ***c***<sub>3</sub>

to

***x***<sub>1</sub> ***y***<sub>1</sub> ***z***<sub>1</sub> ["***z***<sub>1</sub>"] ***a***<sub>1</sub> ***b***<sub>1</sub> ***c***<sub>1</sub>

***x***<sub>2</sub> ***y***<sub>2</sub> ***z***<sub>2</sub> ["***z***<sub>2</sub>"] ***a***<sub>2</sub> ***b***<sub>2</sub> ***c***<sub>2</sub>

***x***<sub>3</sub> ***y***<sub>3</sub> ***z***<sub>3</sub> ["***z***<sub>3</sub>"] ***a***<sub>3</sub> ***b***<sub>3</sub> ***c***<sub>3</sub>

where *x*, *y*, *z*, *a*, *b* and *c* are strings seperated by spaces.

another example:

apples bananas pears grapes oranges lemons

to

apples bananas pears grapes fruit:(grapes) oranges lemons

and so on.

Comment: You need to provide more definition.  Regex is about pattern matching of the string's contents.  "complex terms" could mean anything.  You have not defined the string's contents.  Can we assume space delimiters?  In other words, can a complex term contain space?

Comment: Can you provide a more complex example? Bare in mind that notepad++ support only basic regex syntax.

Comment: Please provide one actual input string and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the find put...

```
(\w\s\w\s\w\s)
```

in the replace put

```
\1["z"]
```

See this question for more info.
[NotePad++ replace problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218063/notepad-replace-problem)

I guess this would also make sense for the find...

```
(x[ ]y[ ]z[ ])
```

for your example... if it was the 3rd item it would be

find:

```
(\w\s\w\s)(\w)
```

replace

```
\1\2 fruit(\2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have one group that matches your elements, for example `[1-9]` and there is another group, that matches the separator between your elements, for example `[\,\.]`, then you can write the following

```
 ([1-9][\,\.]){n}([\,\.])([1-9][\,\.])*
```

This will match the first n elements and the separator after it.

You can then use the matched pattern to substitute the content of the second match with your values.

Is that is something you're looking for?